# Pause game after Home button clicked

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Hello i have a Pause Menu that appears after i clicked on the pause button or on the back button. now i want that it will appear after i clicked on Home button.
I tried to put the pauseFuntion on the onPause function but when i back to my app it is restarting the activity.
i even tried to put the pause function on the onStop function but the app crashed.

my pause function:

```
private void ShowPauseMenu(){
    DialogFragment newFragment = new PauseMenuDialogFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Pause");
}
```

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your use case, there should be no problem if you treat the `onResume()` callback correctly. I mean make sure you override `onResume` and do whatever you want: resume the game, etc.

I think the `onResume` has some code that's restarting the app.

EDIT:
Your app crashed in the `onStop()` because the FragmentManager is not anymore available. Try to call the super.onStop() after you do your stuff.

Comment: i thought about this, but if i add the function to the onResume() function, the pause menu appears even when the activity just created(on the first start. i think that the onStop function restart the activity.. but not sure about this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the Home button behavior in your app.

Use the sample as below:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
        //Call the pause function                     
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: it is still doesn't work, when i back to the app the activity is restarting.

Comment: are you sure it's `true` and not `false`? Just curious, because i was never sure which one meant which in this method.

Comment: It should be true. Are you saving the app state?

Comment: i don't think so, how to save them?

Comment: There is another function available as an override for activities. You save the required data and values. onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState). And in onCreate check if savedInstance is not null then assign the required values.

Comment: and when this function calling?

Comment: If you use the onSaveInstanceState way then you do not need to implement any home button listener or anything. Just save the state and read from it in onCreate. The activity lifecycle is defined in a way that onSaveInstanceState will be invoked.